# How to change url in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Currently I am using HelpDeskZ for my office support system.
However, I found out that search function to find a ticket doesn't work.
I am sorry I am still newbie to PHP.

This is the code for search form inside its **filter_bar.html** file:

```html
<form method="get" action="{{ getUrl(controller,'tickets',null,'#searchtab')|raw }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="do" value="search" />
                <table width="100%" class="widget-table-form">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ LANG.SEARCH_IN }}:</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                 <select name="criteria">
                    <option value="code" {% if input.g.criteria == 'code' %}selected{% endif %}>{{ LANG.TICKET_ID }}</option>
                    <option value="subject" {% if input.g.criteria == 'subject' %}selected{% endif %}>{{ LANG.SUBJECT }}</option>
                    <option value="email" {% if input.g.criteria == 'email' %}selected{% endif %}>{{ LANG.EMAIL }}</option>
                    <option value="name" {% if input.g.criteria == 'name' %}selected{% endif %}>{{ LANG.NAME }}</option>
                    </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="criteria_value" style="width:100%" value="{{ input.g.criteria_value }}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">{{ LANG.STATUS }}:</td>
                        <td><select name="status">
                        <option value="">{{ LANG.ANY_STATUS }}</option>
                        {% for id, name in ticket_status %}
                        {% if input.g.status == id %}
                        <option value="{{ id }}" selected>{{ name }}</option>
                        {% else %}
                        <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td align="right">{{ LANG.DEPARTMENT }}:</td>
                        <td><select name="department_id">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            {% for id, name in departments %}
                            {% if input.g.department_id == id %}
                            <option value="{{ id }}" selected>{{ name }}</option>
                            {% else %}
                            <option value="{{ id }}">{{ name }}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="right">{{ LANG.PRIORITY }}:</td>
                        <td><select name="priority_id">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            {% for key in priority %}
                            {% if input.g.priority_id == key.id %}
                            <option value="{{ key.id }}" selected>{{ key.name }}</option>
                            {% else %}
                            <option value="{{ key.id }}">{{ key.name }}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">{{ LANG.FROM }}:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from" value="{{ input.g.date_from }}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">{{ LANG.TO }}:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="date_to" id="date_to" value="{{ input.g.date_to }}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btn" value="{{ LANG.SEARCH }}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

But, when I click search button, it will goes to:

> http://localhost/support/?do=search&criteria=code&criteria_value=111&status=1&department_id=1&priority_id=1&date_from=&date_to=&btn=Search#searchtab

After I do a research, the URL is incorrect.
It's should goes to:

> http://localhost/support/?v=staff&action=tickets&do=search&criteria=code&criteria_value=111&status=1&department_id=1&priority_id=1&date_from=&date_to=&btn=Search#searchtab

As you can see, there is another parameter after the http://localhost/support/ URL, which is **?v=staff&action=tickets**

I tried to search on the **tickets_action.php** inside its controller folder, but I don't know how to edit it.
This is the controller:

```html
<?php
/**
 * @package HelpDeskZ
 * @website: http://www.helpdeskz.com
 * @community: http://community.helpdeskz.com
 * @author Evolution Script S.A.C.
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
//Query String
$getvar = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
//Ticket Status
$ticket_status = array(1 => $LANG['OPEN'], 2 => $LANG['ANSWERED'], 3 => $LANG['AWAITING_REPLY'], 4 => $LANG['IN_PROGRESS'], 5 => $LANG['CLOSED']);
$template_vars['ticket_status'] = $ticket_status;
//Status Color
$statuscolor = array('1' => '#008000',
     '2' => '#b84764',
     '3' => '#ff8000',
     '4' => '#53a9ff',
     '5' => '#333333',      
     );

//Departments
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."departments");
$departments = array();
while($r = $db->fetch_array($q)){
 if(in_array($r['id'],$staff_departments)){
  $departments[$r['id']] = $r['name'];
 }else{
  $exceptiondep_query .= " AND department_id!={$r['id']}";
 }
}
$template_vars['departments'] = $departments;
//Priority
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."priority");
while($r = $db->fetch_array($q)){
 $priority[$r['id']] = $r;
}
$template_vars['priority'] = $priority;

//Filter bar
$filter_query = ($exceptiondep_query == ''?'':'WHERE '.substr($exceptiondep_query, 4));
$totalticket = $db->query("SELECT status, department_id, COUNT(id) as total FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."tickets {$filter_query} GROUP by status, department_id");
while($r = $db->fetch_array($totalticket)){
 $total_dep[$r['department_id']][$r['status']] = $r['total'];
}
$searchurl = getUrl($controller,'tickets',null,'do=search&');
foreach($departments as $dep_id => $dep_name){
 $data = array('id' => $dep_id, 'pId' => 0, 'name' => '<strong>'.$dep_name.'</strong>', 'open' => 'true', 'isParent' => 'true','url' => $searchurl.'department_id='.$dep_id, 'target' => '_parent');
 
 $data1 = array('id' => $dep_id.'1', 'pId' => $dep_id, 'name' => $LANG['OPEN'].' '.($total_dep[$dep_id]['1'] != ''?'<span class="fancytree_descr">( '.$total_dep[$dep_id]['1'].' )</span>':''), 'url' => $searchurl.'status=1&department_id='.$dep_id, 'target' => '_parent');
 
 $data2 = array('id' => $dep_id.'2', 'pId' => $dep_id, 'name' => $LANG['AWAITING_REPLY'].' '.($total_dep[$dep_id]['3'] != ''?'<span class="fancytree_descr">( '.$total_dep[$dep_id]['3'].' )</span>':''), 'url' => $searchurl.'status=3&department_id='.$dep_id, 'target' => '_parent');
 
 $data3 = array('id' => $dep_id.'3', 'pId' => $dep_id, 'name' => $LANG['IN_PROGRESS'].' '.($total_dep[$dep_id]['4'] != ''?'<span class="fancytree_descr">( '.$total_dep[$dep_id]['4'].' )</span>':''), 'url' => $searchurl.'status=4&department_id='.$dep_id, 'target' => '_parent');
 
 $data4 = array('id' => $dep_id.'4', 'pId' => $dep_id, 'name' => $LANG['ANSWERED'].' '.($total_dep[$dep_id]['2'] != ''?'<span class="fancytree_descr">( '.$total_dep[$dep_id]['2'].' )</span>':''), 'url' => $searchurl.'status=2&department_id='.$dep_id, 'target' => '_parent');
 
 $data5 = array('id' => $dep_id.'5', 'pId' => $dep_id, 'name' => $LANG['CLOSED'].' '.($total_dep[$dep_id]['5'] != ''?'<span class="fancytree_descr">( '.$total_dep[$dep_id]['5'].' )</span>':''), 'url' => $searchurl.'status=5&department_id='.$dep_id, 'target' => '_parent');
 $filter_bar .= json_encode($data).','.json_encode($data1).','.json_encode($data2).','.json_encode($data3).','.json_encode($data4).','.json_encode($data5).',';
}
$template_vars['filter_bar'] = $filter_bar;

if($params[0] == 'view' && is_numeric($params[1])){
 include(CONTROLLERS.'staff/params/tickets_view.php');
}elseif($params[0] == 'canned'){
 include(CONTROLLERS.'staff/params/tickets_canned.php');
}

$search_query = '';
if($input->g['do'] == 'search'){
 if(array_key_exists($input->g['status'],$ticket_status)){
  $search_query .= "status='".$db->real_escape_string($input->g['status'])."' AND ";
 }else{
  $search_query .= "status!='test' AND ";
 }

 if(array_key_exists($input->g['department_id'],$departments) && in_array($input->g['department_id'], $staff_departments)){
  $search_query .= "department_id='".$db->real_escape_string($input->g['department_id'])."' AND ";
 }
 if(array_key_exists($input->g['priority_id'],$priority)){
  $search_query .= "priority_id='".$db->real_escape_string($input->g['priority_id'])."' AND ";
 }
 if(!empty($input->g['date_from'])){
  $daterange = daterange($input->g['date_from']);
  if($daterange != ''){
   $date_from = $daterange[0];
   $search_query .= "date>='$date_from' AND ";
  } 
 }
 if(!empty($input->g['date_to'])){
  $daterange = daterange($input->g['date_to']);
  if($daterange != ''){
   $date_to = $daterange[1]; 
   $search_query .= "date<='$date_to' AND ";
  } 
 }
 if(!empty($input->g['criteria_value'])){
  switch($input->g['criteria']){
   case 'code':
   $search_query .= "code='".$db->real_escape_string($input->g['criteria_value'])."' AND ";
   break;
   case 'subject':
   $search_query .= "subject LIKE '%".$db->real_escape_string($input->g['criteria_value'])."%' AND ";
   break;
   case 'name':
   $search_query .= "fullname LIKE '%".$db->real_escape_string($input->g['criteria_value'])."%' AND ";
   break;
   case 'email':
   $search_query .= "email='".$db->real_escape_string($input->g['criteria_value'])."' AND ";
   break;
  }
 }
}

if($search_query){
 $search_query = substr($search_query,0,-5); 
}else{
 $search_query = "status!='5' AND status!='2'";
}
   
if($params[0] == 'page'){
 $page = (!is_numeric($params[1])?1:$params[1]);
}else{
 $page = 1; 
}

$order_list = array('code', 'subject', 'last_replier', 'replies', 'priority_id', 'last_update', 'department_id', 'status');
$orderby = (in_array($params[2],$order_list)?$params[2]:'last_update');
$sortby = ($params[3] == 'asc'?'asc':'desc');

if($input->p['do'] == 'update'){
 if(verifyToken('tickets', $input->p['csrfhash']) !== true){
  $error_msg = $LANG['CSRF_ERROR']; 
 }elseif(!is_array($input->p['ticket_id'])){
  $error_msg = $LANG['NO_SELECT_TICKET']; 
 }else{
  foreach($input->p['ticket_id'] as $k){
   if(is_numeric($k)){
    $ticketid = $db->real_escape_string($k);
    if($input->p['remove'] == 1){
     $db->delete(TABLE_PREFIX."tickets", "id='$ticketid'");      
     $db->delete(TABLE_PREFIX."tickets_messages", "ticket_id='$ticketid'");  
     removeAttachment($ticketid,'tickets');   
    }else{
     if(array_key_exists($input->p['department'],$departments)){
      $db->query("UPDATE ".TABLE_PREFIX."tickets SET department_id='".$db->real_escape_string($input->p['department'])."' WHERE id='$ticketid'");
     }
     if(array_key_exists($input->p['status'],$statuscolor)){
      $db->query("UPDATE ".TABLE_PREFIX."tickets SET status='".$db->real_escape_string($input->p['status'])."' WHERE id='$ticketid'");
     }
     if(array_key_exists($input->p['priority'],$priority)){
      $db->query("UPDATE ".TABLE_PREFIX."tickets SET priority_id='".$db->real_escape_string($input->p['priority'])."' WHERE id='$ticketid'");
     }
    }
   }
  }
  header('location: '.getUrl($controller,$action,array('page',$page,$orderby,$sortby),$getvar));
  exit;
 }
}


$max_results = $settings['page_size'];
$count = $db->fetchOne("SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."tickets WHERE {$search_query} {$exceptiondep_query}");
$total_pages = ceil($count/$max_results); 
$page = ($page>$total_pages?$total_pages:$page);
$from = ($max_results*$page) - $max_results;
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."tickets WHERE {$search_query} {$exceptiondep_query} ORDER BY {$orderby} {$sortby} LIMIT $from, $max_results");
$todayis = time();

while($r = $db->fetch_array($q)){
 $trzebra = ($trzebra == ''?1:'');
 $timeleft = $todayis-$r['last_update'];
 $overdue = ($timeleft >=($settings['overdue_time']*60*60) && ($r['status'] == '1' || $r['status'] == '2' || $r['status'] == '4')?1:0);
 if($overdue == 1){
  $colortime = '#ff0000';
  $tdclass = 'troverdue';
 }else{
  $colortime = '#8bb467';
  $tdclass = ($trzebra == 1?'trzebra':'');     
 }
 
 $days = floor($timeleft/86400);
 $hours = floor($timeleft/3600)-($days*24);
 $minutes = floor($timeleft/60)-($days*24*60)-($hours*60);
 $seconds = $timeleft-($days*24*60*60)-($hours*60*60)-($minutes*60);
 $r['lastupdate'] = ($days?$days.'d ':'').($hours?$hours.'h ':'').($minutes?$minutes.'m ':'').($days?'':$seconds.'s');
 $r['priority'] = $priority[$r['priority_id']]['name'];
 $r['priority_color'] = $priority[$r['priority_id']]['color'];
 $r['color_time'] = $colortime;
 $r['td_class'] = $tdclass;
 $tickets[] = $r;
}
$template_vars['total_tickets'] = $count;
$template_vars['tickets'] = $tickets;
$template_vars['total_pages'] = $total_pages;
$template_vars['page'] = $page;
$template_vars['orderby'] = $orderby;
$template_vars['sortby'] = $sortby;
$template_vars['getvar'] = $getvar;
$template_vars['error_msg'] = $error_msg;
$template_vars['statuscolor'] = $statuscolor;
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('tickets.html');
echo $template->render($template_vars);
$db->close();
exit;
?>
```

Any ideas how to change the URL to the correct one?

Thank You!

**NB**: You can refer to https://github.com/evolutionscript/HelpDeskZ-1.0/archive/master.zip to download the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a quick solution to this problem.

Open the file:  views/staff/filter_bar.htm

after line 46 which is

```
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="search" />
```

Add these two lines after:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="tickets" />
<input type="hidden" name="v" value="staff" />
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I just realized it uses hidden input.